# How to handle curved paths in maze

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, localization, raspberry-pi

-I have an RPi on Ubuntu with ROS (Kinetic). The task is to solve a maze. I have implemented a left-hand algorithm to navigate through the maze.

-The robot is equipped with 3 ultrasonic HC-SR04 sensors.

How do I detect and navigate through a curved path using these sensors?

Answer (score 1):

Use a distance threshold between the wall and robot and make the robot turn every time the output of sensor is less than the threshold. I guess you are using a differential drive robot. And if you are not mapping, there is no use of other 2 sensors. You just need to create a publisher for the sensor data and subscribe it to calculate the threshold and send the appropriate velocity for the bot.